# Ironpython and GDAL

Tags: ironpython, gdal, arcpy, osgeo, revitpythonshell

I usually use Python 2.7, especially for processing GIS-data.

When I want to work with Revit/Dynamo script, I have to use Ironpython 2.7.
Both version are installed on my computer and they work fine. 
Now I want to integrate some GIS processes in my revit/dynamo enviroment.

Is there a way to use: gdal, numpy and arcpy in Ironpython?

Comment: @AatishSai do not use code formatting for names like python.

Answer (score 1):

This blog post might help with numpy: http://blog.enthought.com/python/scipy-for-net/

As for `gdal` and `arcpy`... have you considered just running CPython in a separate process and using IPC (inter process communication) to do the GIS processes? This can be as simple as a batch-style job, where you write out data to a file, start a cpython script, wait for it to finish and read back in the output.